# How to create a self pointing arrow to a box

Tags: html, css

I am little stuck and need ur help, actually I am stuck in a problem I need to create an self pointing arrow to a rectangular box in css which I am unable to develop it Any help with example would be appreciated.

To understand the problem better I am attaching the desired output image.

[image]

I am also sharing my code what I have tried

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container-2 {
    margin-top: 4em;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Removed left border
2. Added pseudo element::before, could also be div with class arrow
3. Created [triangle arrow](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container-2 {
    margin-top: 4em;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative;
}
.container-2:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give the second box a pseudo element and style it using `clip-path` to make a little arrow:

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container-2 {
    margin-top: 4em;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left-width: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.container-2::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 80% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 50%);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just a `content: "⮜";` like [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69070241/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan That works, too. But I think you can control the appearance of the arrow better using `clip-path`, also the shape will be more consistent using different font/os/character set. (*Not my down vote, btw*)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this pseudo element ::after with a unicode arrow?

I additionally removed the left border

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container-2 {
  margin-top: 4em;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left:0;
}

.container-2::after {
  content: "⮜";
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container-2"></div>
</div>
```